# Github Actions Parameter Not Found in Template

Tags: github-actions, aws-cloudformation

Attempting to move infrastructure from CDK back to Cloudformation templates using github actions

Am utilising the github action aws-cloudformation-github-deploy

```
- name: Deploy to AWS CloudFormation
        uses: aws-actions/aws-cloudformation-github-deploy@v1
        with:
          name: service-name
          template: stack.yaml
          parameter-overrides: "Env=stg"
```

Stack.yaml snippet generated from CDK

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Accounts API Infrastructure

Parameters:
  Env:
    Description: Environment to be deployed
    Type: String
    
Resources:
  SecurityGroupA0B2798B:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
```

Am continually getting `Parameters: [Env] do not exist in the template` even though it is seen in the stack template.

Have also added the Parameters to the original CDK deployment

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from a working GitHub Action

```
    - name: Deploy with AWS CloudFormation
      uses: aws-actions/aws-cloudformation-github-deploy@v1
      with:
        name: service-name
        template: stack.yaml
        parameter-overrides: >-
          FirstParameter=stg,            
          SecondParameter=something
```